# iPhone Push notificaton

Tags: iphone, push-notification

Is it possible send push notification without server side?

For example my device cominicates with apns directly without server?

Comment: Please do not post whole question in **bold**. Only use bold to highlight important facts.

Comment: And which event should trigger your push notification then?

Answer (score 1):

While technically it is possible, it isn't something you would want to do.

You would have to embed your certificate inside your app. This would be a BadThing. Anyone who wanted to could then extract your certificate and start sending push notifications pretending to be you.

The apns is only there to push notifications out to the devices. It isn't a two-way communication thing other than the devices register with it. Once they have registered, the apns sends messages when you request them.

If you don't want to write your own server, there are others available that are already written like the excellent (I don't work for them - just a happy user) Urban Airship.